# Which font is this? (from a Creative Review email)

Tags: font-identification

Seems to have a kind of 70s look to it. Or at least that's what it reminds me of.

[image]

I am talking about the bit in italics of course.

Thanks very much.

Comment: What steps have you taken so far to determine the font?  Have you already tried the automated services?

Comment: WhatTheFont calls it Minion Pro but that's not a perfect match as can be seen by, for example, the lower case "a"

Comment: When life doesn't give you lemons, you just need to pretend that you have enough of them anyways.

Comment: To my amateur eye, it's close to Bembo Semibold Ital: http://www.fonts.com/findfonts/detail.htm?productid=215079 . Except for the traitorous, crummy-looking y-descender in the linked page.

Comment: I'd ask the sender… seriously.

Comment: Sorry, Lollero, that doesn't look *anything* like ICG Lemonade. :)

Comment: Searched. Still no clue.

Paul Pensom, Art Director, Creative Review - paul.pensom@centaur.co.uk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [Lyon Text Regular Italic](http://www.carvalho-bernau.com/retailfonts/lyon-overview), I believe.

The text in blue is from the [Commercial Type](http://commercialtype.com/type_test) "type test" (their name, not mine) - the font is also available from that site.  I did a quick overlay of the two just to make sure.

Rob

[image]